# Accidently created ~ in current directory how do I get rid of it without deleting the home directory

Tags: linux, bash, tcsh

I accidently created a ~ (tilda => home shortcut) in my current directory. How do I get rid of it without deleting the home directory.

Comment: Use `rm -r -- ./~`

Answer (score 2):

Prepend the `~` with a backslash ...

```
tink@box ~/tmp$ touch \~
tink@box ~/tmp$ ls -ltr
total 28
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink  161 2020-11-21 05:40 saad
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink   31 2020-11-21 09:10 login.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tink tink  213 2020-11-21 09:50 sh.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink 1054 2020-11-23 21:16 hasla.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink    0 2020-12-23 06:43 ~
tink@box ~/tmp$ rm \~
tink@box ~/tmp$ ls -ltr
total 28
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink  161 2020-11-21 05:40 saad
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink   31 2020-11-21 09:10 login.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tink tink  213 2020-11-21 09:50 sh.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tink tink 1054 2020-11-23 21:16 hasla.txt
```

Comment: gives a `rm: cannot remove ‘~’: Is a directory`

Comment: Is it safe to use `-f`?

Comment: You had said file, not directory.. but yes, that is perfectly safe `rm -rf \~` (if you're in the directory where you created `~` ...)

Comment: If you want to delete a directory and want to be safe that you're just deleting an empty directory, then use `rmdir` @Coddy: `rmdir \~`. If you make a mistake you'll get an error: `rmdir ~` gives: `rmdir: failed to remove '/home/martin': Permission denied`. `rmdir` will *only* delete empty directories, and us much safer than `rm -r` which would delete my home dir :-)